# Android - change dialog title style of all dialogs in application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme

Is there a way I can change all the alert dialogs appearing in my Android application? I want to change the dialogs that are system generated as well (*like the Edit Text dialog that opens up when you long tap on any EditText*). I want to change the title font color and size of all the dialogs in my app.

Is there a way to do it?

I have tried setting `android:alertDialogTheme` in my theme. But it seems to be not working.  Code following -

```
<style name="Theme.DLight" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="android:Theme" >    
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#014076</item>       
</style>
```

**EDIT**

> I'm not invoking a dialog from my code. It's just the default dialog
>   that appears when you long click on any EditText. Generally it
>   contains the keyboard options like Select word, Select all, Input
>   method etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In you dialog theme, the attribute you need to modify `windowTitleStyle`. There, reference a style for your title and define a text appearance for this title. For example, to display your title red and bold:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    ...  
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.AlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogStyle" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.Alert">    
    ...
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle_Custom</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogWindowTitle_Custom" parent="@style/DialogWindowTitle_Holo">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance_DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance_DialogWindowTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

If you want to style a little bit more your AlertDialog, I wrote a [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200214041924/http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/) detailing the steps.

Answer (score 6):

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       //All your other styles and add the one mntioned below.

        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>
    </style>
```

In the styles of AlertDialog add:

```
 <style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title</item>
    </style>
```

**windowTitleStyle** is important to add as it will give your title that effect that you need.

Now simply use this Theme in your AlertDialog in any activity that you want like below:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
```

Comment: If it's necessary to pass the style to `Builder`, why have it in the app theme as well?